# designing a class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, frameworks

I am designing  a class which comprises of objects of other classes, right now i am accepting the values to instantiate this class via function parameters. This class is created per session(From the user login to logout). For a session the UserInteraction object will be global i.e:- It can be used from any file at any time. I am planning to allocate memory to the object at user login  so that at every user login the object will be 'new'.

However i am getting a feeling that i am not doing things right. Please advice if I can use any other patterns to improve the code.

```
class UserInteraction
    {
        private UserDetails _loginDetails; // information of the user logged in.
        private UserFiles[] _userFilesDownloaded; // files downloaded for the user.
        private PrintStatus _printStatus;   // Details of files printed 

        public UserInteraction() { }

        public UserDetails UserInfo {                
            get { return _loginDetails; }
            set { _loginDetails = value; }
        }

        public PrintStatus Status {
            get { return _printStatus; }
            set { _printStatus = value; }
        }

        public UserFiles[] FilesDownloaded {
            get { return _userFilesDownloaded; }
            set { _userFilesDownloaded = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think there's something wrong in this code? Don't try to apply patterns where they're not needed...

Comment: how many user will be online simoltanously?

Comment: Your indenting could do with some improvement. But besides that, is there a concrete question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you design some class at least be clear with its responsibilities and collaborations (other objects that it depends on , to perform its responsibilities).

Try to think who will instantiate/use this object, its life time and how/when it will be destroyed.

Be clear with these fundamental design principles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design).

As mentioned by @Thomas Levesque,"Don't try to apply patterns where they're not needed...", they are just extensions to good design principles.

Comment: +1, although I do not understand your last statement, please elaborate it.

Comment: @jgauffin I exactly meant what @Thomas Levesque mentioned in his comment.

Comment: why not ask that question then?

Comment: may be, the latest edit should be okay with @jgauffin and @Jodrell :)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to write

```
Class UserInteraction
{
    public UserDetails UserInfo { get; set; }
    public PrintStatus Status { get; set; }
    public IList<UserFiles> FilesDownloaded { get; set; }
}
```

As we can see this class doesent actually have any functionality. Questions I would start with are, is `UserInteraction` some abstract entity, what binds this info together. What do you mean by global?

"Sucking eggs here" I describe my problem and what I want to achive in good english. Then I consider each noun I've used as a possible class name. Whether or not this is right depends on the context of your problem.

**EDIT** It sounds like you want the [Singleton Pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), or perhaps a singleton to hold an `IList` of users

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the constructor, while instantiating the class **UserInteraction** like below

```
UserInteraction obj = new UserInteraction
{
     UserInfo = some Value;
     Status   = some Value;
     FilesDownloaded = some Value;
};
```

The Get and Set are not required in case the property is read/write. It can be written as follows according to my understanding.

```
public UserDetails UserInfo{ get; set; } 
public PrintStatus Status{ get; set; } 
public UserDetails UserInfo{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the excellent advice by KKK4SO, and you still want this, you could try to implement a Singleton pattern: [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)